# How to reserve Drive Letter to USB drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb

I have few USB portable drives which I keep on changing. Is there a way to reserve a perticular letter to each drive?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

When you plug in the USB drive, you need to access "Computer Management".  On Win XP its in Start / Administrative Tools / Computer Management, if you don't have it, follow a tutorial on this.

Now once you're there nav to *Storage / Disk Management*. From there find the USB drive you want to re-assign, and right click it and choose "Change drive letter and paths".

When you give a USB device a new letter your system will actually re-assign it that same letter when you plug it in the next time.

Comment: This sort of works but breaks every time you connect a new (not configured previously) drive while your old drives are not connected. E.g. whenever I plug a new drive while my main thumbdrive (which I want to be D:) is not connected, the new drive would take D: or whatever the first letter not taken by a currently mounted drive.

Answer (score 0):

from google of "How to reserve Drive Letter to USB drive"

USBDLM V4.5.8 - USB Drive Letter Manager for Windows 2000, XP and higher

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

Never used it, but looks promising.

Comment: Windows supports the ability natively

Comment: Yes, but it requires you have the necessary privileges. USBDLM appears to offer functionality around that. From the linked page:
"Running as service makes it independent of the logged on user's privileges, so there is no need to give the users the privilege to change drive letters."  
Not worth a down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar (same?) [question](https://superuser.com/questions/98924/how-do-i-make-an-external-hard-drive-keep-the-same-drive-letter-permanently). The answer was basically [USBDLM](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html).

Comment: That answer was already given.

Comment: Yes but my point was that a)the question already exists and b)as it's been around a while, that's likely to be the best answer.